# Finding a definite integral by residue integration?

Tags: probability, integration, residue-calculus

I have a probability distribution of the form
$$\frac{k_1}{(k_2 x^2+k_3 x+k_4)^n}$$
and I want to find the mean and variance—but am running into problems with that.

The mean would be
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k_1 x\,dx}{(k_2 x^2+k_3 x+k_4)^n}$$
and the variance would be similar stuff. The quadratic form in the denominator is guaranteed to have to complex roots, by the way, and $k_2>0$, so it's a positive parabola with a minimum which is greater than $0$ (and it's also to the $n$th power, where $n$ is a natural number), and of course $k_1$ is such that the whole thing integrates to $1$. Obviously if $n=1$, then it's just a skip, hop and a jump away from the integral of the arctangent, but that doesn't help me when $n>1$. I not only have not had success with integrating it using substitution, but I went to the wolfram online integrator and it gave me a reference to something I can't find out information about that I need. But it's just a definite integral I want anyway, I want the mean and variance, that's all I want. For all I know this is a well known probability distribution and its mean and variance are known and I don't need to figure out anything. I also was thinking residue integration could do the job, I remember doing things like finding $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^4+1},$$ which is kind of up the same alley, but I can't for the life of me remember how this is done and I can't understand any of the explanations I find in the first page of search results on how to find integrals using residue integration. Can someone tell me if this is a probability distribution that actually has a name, or help me either solving the integral or just tell me what the mean and variance are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you observe, it suffices to compute the integral
$$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+1)^n}$$
for integral $n>0$, which turns out to evaluate nicely:
$$I_n=\dfrac{\pi}{2^{2n-2}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}.$$

This is indeed a standard application of residue calculus.  The denominator factors as $(x+i)^n(x-i)^n$, so the integrand $f(x)$ has poles at $-i$ and $i$.  Select a contour consisting of a line segment from $-R$ to $R$, followed by a semicircular arc of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane connecting $R$ back to $-R$.  The only pole enclosed is at $z=i$, and the arc contribution to the integral is negligible as $R\to\infty$, so $$I_n=2\pi i\, \textrm{Res}_{z=i} f(z).$$

Computing the residue is straightforward: 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\textrm{Res}_{z=i} f(z) &=& \lim_{z\to i}\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left((z-i)^n f(z)\right)\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\dfrac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} (z+i)^{-n}\big|_{z=i}\\
&=& \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!} (-n)(-n-1)\cdots(-2n+2) (2i)^{-2n+1}\\
&=& \binom{2n-2}{n-1} \dfrac{-i}{2^{2n-1}}.\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
Multiplying by $2\pi i$ gives the claimed formula for $I_n$.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I think this is what really gets me where I need to go, with a linear transformation I can put it in the form you first show with just $(x^2+1)^n$ in the denominator since it is just translated to the side by the $x^1$ term and scaled up or down and moved up or down by the others so long as the roots are all complex, and that definite integral is the key to it all. Although things might get a little messy. Hopefully not as messy as my use of integration by parts, where I had to try to solve a 5x5 linear system with variables in the matrix entries (answer at end didn't work)!

Comment: I just did it using this expression! And it works with some examples using specific numbers, checked against evaluating the integral numerically, so I KNOW it's good. The variance is $\frac{k_2*k_4-.25*k_3^2}{k_2^2*(2*k_5-3)}$ and of course the mean is $-.5*k_3/k_2$. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $n\gt1$ (otherwise the mean does not exist) and $k_2\ne0$ (the case $k_2=0$ being direct), and let $P(x)=k_2x^2+k_3x+k_4$, then $P'(x)=2k_2x+k_3$ hence
$$
\frac{k_1x}{P(x)^n}=\frac{k_1}{2k_2}\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)^n}-\frac{k_3}{2k_2}\frac{k_1}{P(x)^n}.
$$
Since $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{k_1}{P(x)^n}\mathrm dx=1$ and $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)^n}\mathrm dx=-\frac1{n-1}\left.\frac1{P(x)^{n-1}}\right|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=0$ because $n\gt1$, this yields
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{k_1x}{P(x)^n}\mathrm dx=-\frac{k_3}{2k_2}.
$$
A similar decomposition of $x^2$ in the basis $(P(x),P'(x),1)$ yields the variance when $n\gt\frac32$, provided one knows the value of the integral
$$
I_{n-1}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{P(x)^{n-1}}.
$$
A simple approach to this computation is to express the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}t^nI_n$ as the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{t\,\mathrm dx}{P(x)-t},
$$
to compute this integral, to expand the result as a series, and to identify $I_n$ as the coefficient of $t^n$ in this expansion. In the present case, no difficulty is involved, and this route seems at least as direct as the approach based on complex analysis.

Comment: Well, I actually managed to find the mean a few minutes after I posted this, although apparently by a different method - I used the property that $k_1$ was such that the probability density integrated to 1, and that an odd function integrates to 0 - since the denominator is even about center $-.5*k_3/k_2$, so having $(x+.5*k_3/k_2)^{2*m+1}$ in the numerator for m a whole number makes it integrate to 0. But this didn't help in finding the expected value of $x^2$, whereas you suggest your method would work to find it. I see what you did, but still can't figure out the methodology of your steps.

Comment: Sorry but the question in your comment (if there is one) is not precise enough for me to answer it.

Comment: I wanted to know why you did what you did so that I could use the same method to do it to find the expected value of $x^2$. But you are also saying that I need to know the value of the integral with $P(x)^{n-1}$ in the denominator and I don't.

Comment: What I have done is try integration by parts, which leaves n+1 as the power of the exponent in the denominator, and then trying to separate it into a sum of 5 things so that I can cancel out the last power in the exponent in the denominator and make it n again: $k_2*x^2+k_3*x+k4$, $k_2*x^3+k_3*x^2+k_4*x$, $k_2*x^4+k_3*x^3+k_4*x^2$, and because they integrate to 0, the odd components: $(x+.5*k_3/k_2)$ and $(x+.5*k_3/k_2)^3$, but I get this MESS I likely messed up on, because it's just so complicated and I probably made a mistake somewhere, and it isn't this short and sweet formula.

Comment: It would be nice if you have heard of this probability distribution and might tell me what it's called - because the way I got it wasn't something completely arbitrary, it was actually the superposition of the gaussian distributions that best fit some data, weighted by how likely the data is to arise given each gaussian mean and variance, and then integrating over all possible means and variances. Basically, the result of a doubly random variable, a gaussian with uncertain mean/variance. So it seems like it ought to be a standard probability distribution that is well known and has a name.